# iOS 7: detect if App autoupdating is enabled?

Tags: ios, ios7

Is there an API or a hack to detect whether or not automatic updating has been enabled globally on iOS 7?

This setting may impact whether or not developers want to notify the user about available app upgrades. For example, we don't want to bug the user if they are running an old version of our app, but auto-update is allowed.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Very good question! I'm curious if someone knows an answer. +1

Comment: If it's important that the user knows about the new version (e.g. API endpoints will break), just do it anyway. If their old version won't stop working - don't. Consider that if the user doesn't even know how updating an app works, you'd have to give them some instructions on how to do this etc. Users who know how it works have probably chosen not to upgrade the app for some reason, and thus also don't care.

Comment: @millimoose There may be users who have disabled autoupdate for some reason, but still care that a new version is available. We want to let that segment know that we've been working to improve the App, without inconveniencing those who are about to get the upgrade through auto-updating.

Comment: How about this: after an arbitrary number of times bringing the app to the foreground, ask the customer if they want to be notified of new versions of the app. A simple alert with Yes and No buttons. Store the result in NSUserDefaults. You could even let the customer change their opt-in status any time they wish via a Settings.bundle or in-app settings view. 

No need for Apple-supplied APIs, no hacks that will get the app rejected by Apple, and it shows respect for the customer by asking them to opt in.

Comment: Good point about risk due to non-Apple API hacks. At the crux of the matter, though, is respecting the user by minimizing the amount of obtrusive dialogs we show. Knowing whether or not updates are enabled allows us to show as few as possible.

Comment: Is displaying a one-time alert really that obtrusive? Many apps already do this to solicit App Store reviews.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no API. This is to stop developers from bugging users who don't want to upgrade.

Comment: I certainly hope this is the case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question to better reflect what this question is about... to find an API or a hack of some kind to find out whether this switch is flipped in the Settings App.